# Могут ли главное и зависимое слово поменяться местами

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Дом.задание: придумать и записать словосочетания. Например: сок малины - малиновый сок, мороз ночью - ночной мороз? или морозная ночь? Как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Мороз ночью - главное слово "мороз", с зависимым словом соединяется по принципу примыкания, нужно главное слово оставить, а зависимое слово присоединить с помощью согласования - **ночной мороз.**